# Project Dll Copy error in other project

Tags: .net, winforms

> > I am develop one project in Dot net windows application, with more then one project in One solution, all project are called in one main project. What my problem is "When i compile solution dll is create their own project folder, but in that dll did not copy in main project. so when ever i change a small part of code i manually do that copy and paste that main project after that run my project". what is the problem of that, any one can help that problem,
> >
> > Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main project references, right-click on each of the projects - select properties and in the properties window set Copy Local to true

Answer (score 0):

Open client project References, and set `Copy Local = True` for this Dll.

Details: Open main project in Solution Explorer. Expand References, select Dll reference, open Properties window. Set Copy Local = True.

Comment: Does it copy Dll if it doesn't exist in the main project output directory? Possibly some problem with file access date and time.

Comment: my App.config file also not their in any of that solution, if that any problem